# How to create an aggregate of strategies in Pinescipt

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency

I have coded a few strategies in Pinescript, all of these strategies are binary meaning they are all either 100% long or short at a given moment. I now want to create a indicator that runs all of these strategies on whatever chart i am looking at and then displays in a table whether strategy #1 is long or short and wether strategy #2 is long or short. At the moment i have no idea where to even start and would really appreciate some help. If you help i can even share the strategies because they are Absolute bangers. Do i need to publish the strategies first? publish them as strategies or as libraries?

I have tried asking a few people i know or research a way of doing this however i have yet to find any indicator as to how i should excecute this idea.